# How to get TFS query result but for a previous date

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to execute a TFS query and get the results not for today but for a previous date?

I just want to see the results that were available in that date.

To clarify: I need to see the state of the work items on a give date to see their evolution over time.

Comment: using code and WIQL you can use an AS OF operator, sorry, I currently don't have a link or sample. So please can anyone hijack this comment and create a proper answer that is worth being posted ;)

Comment: Well, thanks for trying anyway :) I though this was something easy to achieve. Do you mean I will have to code my own tool?

Comment: I'm not sure when it was made available but certainly in later versions of TFS you can use the **@Today** token and you can subtract days. e.g. **@Today - 7** for items as at last week. Not sure if that will help you as you would obviously need a date condition in your where clause.

Comment: @Rodders: the @today will be usable in queries like `WHERE ChangeDate > @today -3` but will not help if you want to find workitems `WHERE title='banana' AS OF '1.12.2014'` when the title was changed later. (even if for that case, the `WAS EVER` operator will be sufficient). @Ignacio: Can you edit your question, so that it states what you want to achieve, so that others may be able to answer with an appropriate workaround?

Answer (score 1):

According to your clarification, you need see the state of the work items on a give date. There is not a direct way to achieve it in Work Item Query.

You can only use **Was Ever** in Work Item Query to list items based on State past assignments, like:

```
state Was Ever Active
```

Or you can use `State Change Date <= YYYY-MM-DD` and `State Change Date > YYYY-MM-DD` to list all work items that changed State on YYYY-MM-DD. (Need to check whether TFS 2010 has State Change Date field)

Of course you can combine other clauses to narrow down the query.

What you want is actually the work item history. You need to get the work item history programmatically using TFS API. You can check this blog below to use the API:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/243653/TFS-SDK-Work-Item-History-Visualizer-using-TFS-API

Comment: I normally work only with TFS Explorer. How can I execute a query like this?

Comment: Could you try ChangeDate <= YYYY-MM-DD? Also, if you want to query a state, you can use "State" "Was Ever" "xx" clause?

Comment: By the way, could you provide an example that you want to achieve, so that we can try the clauses to see whether the default query can achieve your requirement?

Comment: How can I execute the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create pivot table report to connect to TFS cube. For your requirement to see work items' evolution over time, you can define the pivot table as:

[image]

Check these two links for the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244678 and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244710.aspx